# Загрузка и отображение изображения в php

Tags: xml, php, dom

Как в php сделать загрузку и отображение изображение. только вместо БД, чтобы использовался xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что сами изображения хранятся в файловой системе или CDN, а в XML хранятся только пути к изображениям.

```
  <images>
     <image url="http://storage/0.jpg" id="0"/>
     <image url="http://storage/1.jpg" id="1"/>
     <image url="http://storage/2.jpg" id="2"/>
  </images>
```

Тогда получить пути можно с помощью SimpleXML

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($images);
$xpath = $xml->xpath("images/image[@id = '0']");

echo $xpath[0]['url'];
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, то что нужно!